# C++11/14 INVOKE workaround

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I need to use the `INVOKE` semantics (implemented by `std::invoke` in C++17) in some C++11/14 code. I certainly don't want to implement it myself, which I believe would be a disaster. So I decided to make use of present standard library facilities. Quickly came to my mind was:

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) my_invoke(Fn&& f, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)()))
{
    return std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
}
```

A problem with this implementation is it can't distinguish between lvalue and rvalue callables (e.g., if a function object overloads on `operator()() &` and `operator()() &&`, only the `&&` version would ever be called). Is there some library utility that also perfect forwards the callable itself? If not, what would be a good way to implement it? (A forwarding wrapper, for example).

Comment: See the sample implementation on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke). It might use some C++17 facilities, but probably can be altered to work in C++11/14

Comment: @ZizhengTai Could you explain why this can't differentiate between lvalue and rvalue callables?

Answer (score 5):

All of `INVOKE`'s special cases are about pointers to members. Just SFINAE on that and ship them to `mem_fn`.

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args, 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_pointer<std::decay_t<Fn>>{}, int> = 0 >
constexpr decltype(auto) my_invoke(Fn&& f, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::mem_fn(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return std::mem_fn(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename Fn, typename... Args, 
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_member_pointer<std::decay_t<Fn>>{}, int> = 0>
constexpr decltype(auto) my_invoke(Fn&& f, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<Fn>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return std::forward<Fn>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This is essentially the minimal implementation proposed in [N4169](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4169.html). (Real standard library implementers don't do this, because it's much more maintainable to centralize the INVOKE functionality in one place and have various other parts just call into it.)

By the way, using `std::bind` is completely wrong. It copies/moves all of the arguments, passes them to the callable as lvalues, and does unwanted magic with reference_wrappers, placeholders, and bind expressions.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't `bind` forward all the arguments?

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. So `bind` copies/moves all the arguments and stores them internally, and when it's eventually invoked, it forwards the stored copies to the callable. Is that correct?

Comment: @ZizhengTai The stored copies are always passed as lvalues, not perfectly forwarded.

Comment: Right...I was somehow mistakening the way `std::bind` works for that of `std::thread`, `std::async`, etc. Thanks for pointing out.