# How to call derived method via function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, pointer-to-member

Consider this example:

```
struct base {
    void method() {};
};

struct foo : base {};

template <typename T,typename R>
void call_it(T& t, R (T::*f)()) {
    (t.*f)();
}

template <typename T,typename B,typename R>
void call_it(T& t, R (B::*f)()) {
    (t.*f)();
}    

int main() {
    base b;
    call_it(b,&base::method);
    foo f;
    call_it(f,&foo::method);
}
```

I was a bit surprised at first that `&foo::method` is a `void (base::*) ()` not a `void (foo::*)()`, but then I realized that I can provide the second overload for `call_it` to enable passing base function pointers together with a reference to a derived object.

Is there a better way to do that? Is the above safe in the sense that it either won't compile or do the right thing?

Comment: How about `call_it(b, [](auto&& o) { o.method()})` ?

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA i would like to avoid any casting or wrapping at the call site

Comment: `template <typename T, typename R> void call_it(T&& t, R&&f) { (t.*f)(); }` ? The syntax would constrain the possibilities, I beleive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288042/c11-14-invoke-workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of the first overload, because the more generic one covers all its use cases.

P.S. This appears to be a (much less generic) re-implementation of `std::invoke`. You might use that instead, if you have access to C++17:

```
std::invoke(&foo::method, f);
```

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to properly tag, I am bound to c++11

Comment: Ah. That's unfortunate.

Comment: anyhow, if what I wrote resembles `std::invoke` then i am fine. It is much less generic because its just what i need

Comment: If you need a `std::invoke` alternative for old standards, there is `boost::hof::apply`.